# MySQL Fulltext vs Like

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, sql-like

**Background** I have a table with max 2000 rows, the user should search up to 6 columns.
I don't know in advance what he's looking for and i want a concatenated search (search1 AND search2 AND...)

**Problem** In these columns I have the an ID not the plain description (ie i have the id of the town, not its name). So I was thinking about two solutions:

1. Create another table, where i put keywords (1 key/row) and then i search there using *LIKE search1% OR LIKE search2% ...*
2. Add a field to the existent table where I put all the keywords and then do a FULLTEXT on that

Which one is the best? I know that rows are so fews that there won't be big perfomance problems, but i hope they'll get more and more :)

**Example**
This is my table:

ID | TOWN | TYPE | ADDRESS |
11| 14132 |  3 | baker street 220
13| 45632 | 8 | main street 12

14132 = London
45632 = New York
3 = Customer
8 = Admin

The user typing "London Customer" should find the first row.

Comment: I don't understand the situation. Can you show your table structure and an example row?

Comment: using search engine is not an option? (like lucene; just don't know what's the server environment you use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're simply going to use a series of LIKEs, then I'd have thought it would make sense to make use of a FULLTEXT index, the main reason being that it would let you use more complex boolean queries in the future. (As @Quassnoi states, you can simply create an index if you don't have a use for a specific field.)

However, it should be noted that fulltext has its limitations - words that are common across all rows have a low "score" and hence won't match as prominently as if you'd carried out a series of LIKEs. (On the flipside, you can of course get a "score" back from a FULLTEXT query, which may be of use depending on how you want to rank the results.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a separate field, since a `FULLTEXT` index can be created on multiple fields:

```
CREATE  fx_mytable_fields ON mytable (field1, field2, field3)

SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   MATCH(field1, field2, field3) AGAINST ('+search1 +search2')
```

This will return all records that contain `search1` and `search2` in either of the fields, like this:

```
field1   field2     field3
--       --         --
search1  something  search2
```

or this:

```
field1           field2      field3
--               --          --
search1 search2  something   something else
```

Comment: yep, but i don't have the query string in this table, i only have the id to make a join

Comment: @tampe125: in this case, you should either use `LIKE` or `REGEXP` (which is slow), use an external `FULLTEXT` engine, like `Sphinx` (which requires installing it) or make an additional denormalized table, index it and fill it on a timely basis.

Answer (score 0):

Given you've got the data in seperate tables, you'd have to have a FULLTEXT index on each of the searchable fields in each table. After that, it's just a matter of building the query with the appropriate JOINs in place so you can fulltext MATCH AGAINST the text version of the field, and not the foreign key number.

```
SELECT user.id, user.name, town.name
FROM user
LEFT JOIN town ON user.town = town.id
WHERE MATCH(user.name, town.name) AGAINST (...)
```